# How a Router Processes IP'S

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I hope I can word this correctly and not get everyone confused. (Sorry if I do!)

For the past couple days, I have been trying to learn all I can about how the inside of a router works. I know the basics but I'm curious of how a router processes it's information. From what I've read so far, does the IP address first go into the router and then while the router's CPU handles the link, does it also go into the RAM and check the 'IP Table' for a list of links it already has and then, after that, check the RAM again for the 'ARP Cache' to see if it already has the MAC Address of the IP Address it's sending the packet to or do I have this completely wrong. Feel free to answer if you can help!

Comment: I'm not really a networking guy, but I think you're talking about a switch (which a home router has built-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have this slightly wrong.  Also, the specifics may vary a bit, but

The router loads the routing table into memory (before handling IP traffic)

The packet (which contains, among other things, source IP, destination IP and source and destination ports and protocol) is picked up off the network card.  It is then matched against the routing table and shoved out the appropriate interface towards the appropriate next hop.

The ARP cache is only used for Ethernet type packets (including "Wifi"), and is used to discover/remember devices reachable on the LAN.  It would only be called upon if the "next hop" is on the LAN side and is not already known.

Often the routing process done in firmware which removes/partially removes the CPU processing bit, and one of the reasons not all devices support IPV6).  Also, routing is often done in conjunction with filtering and/or packet inspection.  There are a number of diagrams on the Internet which show how packets are handled through IPTables - Certainly IPTables/Linux is nowhere near the only game in town, but its very common and gives an idea as to how stuff is processed.   See [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b93070/CNL/v4.0/CNLv4.0.files/Page697.htm) for a simple guide.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are confusing some concepts of Routing with those of Switching. Switching is a Layer2 process (which works closely with the Layer1 media) whereas Routing is a Layer3 process, so its concerned with IP Packets and Routes, largely ignoring Layer2 frame information.

At Layers1 and 2, an electrical signal carrying the data of a Frame, is received and buffered, until the port has enough of the frame to tell where it is going, and then it is either buffered completely, or the stream is directed to a chip (an [ASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit)) that process the MAC address, using either a table of known MACs or broadcast resolution.

Routing however is a somewhat more abstract process (because it occurs at a more abstract layer). Without getting too specific about it (there are entire books on any one of these concepts), routers know Networks, not Hosts, and share information about the networks they know, using protocols like [RIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIP), [OSPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Shortest_Path_First), [(E)IGRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Gateway_Routing_Protocol), [BGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol), etc.

A Router doesn't need to know the path to a given host. It just needs to know the exit interface it should use to send a packet to another router that knows more specifically what to do with it. That's all the router really needs to know to do its job; In fact, most home routers know only two routes, the route to the LAN, and the route to Every other address in the world.

So, if i wanted to send a packet to a server in Hokaido, Japan, from the US, The routing for my packets path might be:

1. My house to the ISP
2. My ISP to the West Coast of the US
3. The west coast to Japan (Tokyo)
4. Tokyo to the North Coast
5. The North Coast to Hokaido
6. Hokiado to the hosts ISP
7. Host ISP to the hosts Neighborhood
8. hosts Neighborhood to the Host site
9. Host site to the exact server

This is not nearly so simple in the real world, but the key principal is, that with every hop, the packet gets to a router that more and more specifically knows how to reach the host. That way, My router, or my ISPs router, or the west coast of the US don't need to know anything about the networks available on japan's north coast.

This is perhaps less technical than you were hoping for, but its important to know the generals before you can dig into the specifics (just like with route aggregation as described above) and frankly, this site is not really the right place to describe every option or process of a Layer3 device.